# C++: Release a node in linked list after it is deleted, How?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

If my code looks like this:

```
struct ListNode{
   int val;
   ListNode *next;
   ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};

ListNode* delete_first_node(ListNode* head){
    ListNode** pp = &head;
    *pp = (*pp)->next;
    return *pp;
}
```

How will C++ release the memory for the "head node" the function is processed?

Comment: This looks like an intrusive linked list; the memory is managed by the user of the collection. Perhaps the ListNodes are living somewhere with automatic storage duration, or live in a `std::deque`.

Comment: "C++" doesn't release any memory . The program code will specify when memory is released. You didn't show any code that releases memory.  There might be code in the rest of the program that releases memory, we don't have a crystal ball.

Answer (score 4):

Function name is misleading, it should simply be named `get_next` as it doesn't `delete` anything. It just returns `head->next` in obfuscating way.

If you want to manage (automatically) memory, you have to change to something like:

```
struct ListNode{
   int val;
   std::unique_ptr<ListNode> next;
   explicit ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
};

void pop_front(std::unique_ptr<ListNode>& head){
    if (head == nullptr) {
        return; // or error
    }
    head = std::move(head->next); // will do the delete for you
}
```

and use it

```
std::unique_ptr<ListNode> head = std::make_unique<ListNode>(42);
// ... fill list as
// head->next = std::make_unique<ListNode>(21);

pop_front(head);
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ generally won't clear the memory by its own and we should do by our own.

```
ListNode** pp = &head;
*pp = (*pp)->next;
```

In your above code, you just moved the head location to next.

instead of doing `*pp = (*pp)->next;`
 you should reset the head position something like,

```
 head = pp->next; -> move the head to next position
 and then delete pp;-> this will delete the memory of the deleted node.
```

please take care of syntax just it's a pseudo code.